# FileZilla SFTP connection through intermediate SSH

Tags: ssh, sftp, putty, filezilla

I am using PuTTY to connect to an intermediate Linux based server. On that server I use `ssh` to connect to the (Linux based) server I try to target. On that server I want to run a program, but I have to send it to that inner server from my PC. A direct connection is not possible.

At the moment I use PSFTP to the intermediate server and PuTTY+`sftp` from the intermediate server to the inner server to send the file, but this takes a lot of work to do everytime.

Is there a way to use FileZilla to set up an SFTP connection to the inner server through the intermediate server?

So in stead of:

- PSFTP: PC -> user@intermediate
- PuTTY: PC -> user@intermediate

  - sftp: user@intermediate -> user@inner

I want:

- FileZilla: PC -> intermediate -> user@inner

Comment: Since nobody had the good sense of migrating the question to SU instead of closing it, I posted it there: [Configuring an SSH tunnel with FileZilla](http://superuser.com/q/1172990/116475)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can setup an SSH tunnel (aka port forwarding) using PuTTY from the intermediate server to the target server and connect with FileZilla to the tunnel.

See details on [port forwarding in PuTTY](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-port-forwarding).

Or see a specific [guide for setting up port forwarding to tunnel file transfer client](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty) (WinSCP particularly, though you can apply it to FileZilla easily).

Actually, WinSCP SFTP client has a (single step) tunneling functionality built in. So, with WinSCP, it is very easy to do what you ask for. See the [*Tunnel* page](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel) of its Advanced Site Settings dialog.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With this I was able to achieve what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: It wouldn't take much for FileZilla to add this feature - I hope they do one day